# external javascript file with embedded ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, charts

I'm trying to embed some rails data in an external js file instead of placing it in a script tag in my .html.haml.  How do I do this?  I looked around and read up on .js.erb stuff, but I'm stumped.  I'm also confused about if/when I should be using .rjs at all for this.  I'm using jquery if this helps.  Thanks!

for more info, basically I'm trying to follow along Ryan Bate's railscast http://asciicasts.com/episodes/223-charts, but put all the graph information in an external js. He mentions that an ajax request should be made when the page is loaded, but I'm not 100% on how to do this.

So far, I've experimented doing the following:

in application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $.ajaxSetup({  
      'beforeSend': function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
   });
   $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: '/graphs'}); 
});
```

graphs.js.erb (random stuff to see if it works):

```
$('.some_container').append('hello!');
$('h1').append('hello!');
```

this seems to work although the hello's appear after a brief delay, and i'm guessing embedded ruby will work too.  however, if I start adding the graph stuff to this .js.erb it stops working (like `data = 1`). also it seems like a lot just to have a dynamic js file.

---

Edit: the 'hello's append in all views, so I must be doing something wrong :/ I only wanted it to append to the profile view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should put that js code in a partial and still use it as html: `_myjavascript.html.erb` (use [javascript_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag) in your partial).

You name your view as myview.js.erb when it should respond to a JS request (not HTML):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render 'myview' }
end
```

Comment: I was thinking about putting it in a partial like that, but it kind of defeats not having to worry about all the tabs and stuff (i'm using haml), and making the html code not have the embedded <script>/more UJS, but if I can't get anything else to work I may do that. 

I don't really understand how to make the myview.js.erb a view--it's just some js I want to run on the .html.erb page.  It works if I'm using link_to and :remote => :true without the other ajax stuff I've tried, but I want the js to load on page load, not only when clicking from a link.

Comment: Then you really must include it in your html view, because it does belong there. You are not obligated to use haml in that partial, use plain erb. Another option is to put it in application.js file.

Comment: Another note: it works when you use :remote => true because that asks for JS content type, not HTML.

Comment: hmm I can't get the partial to work (well, all the way)...
is it ok to put a render partial in a .html.haml if my partial is .html.erb? I used javascript_tag do in my erb, and an alert('hi') works, but nothing related to the plugin works whereas the same code works in the main .html.haml